# How to reference declarative code with typescript transforms?

Tags: typescript

So I have a transform that adds the ability to inline functions, which provides the ability to declare a function to be inlined, and inlines the contents of that function wherever it is used (this works fine).

How can I make the transform work so that I can include the inline-able function from another file? Is there a way I can get the transform out of an import statement?